# UISearchDisplayController in Swift

Tags: ios, search, swift, mapkit, uisearchdisplaycontroller

**I want it work exactly like this.**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gjvw.png

I have a navigation bar with a left and right bar button. The left bar button is a search button. Clicking that button takes me to this method.

```
@IBAction func searchMap(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    var searchDispCont = UISearchDisplayController(searchBar: searchBar, contentsController: nil)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchDispCont.searchBar)

    searchDispCont.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    searchDispCont.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    searchDispCont.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true
    searchDispCont.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    searchDispCont.setActive(true, animated: true)
}
```

When the search bar's cancel button is clicked, it returns to the original navigation controller.

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // Need to go back to original state
    searchBar.hidden = true

    var listBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "List", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goToList:")
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(listBtn, animated: false)

    var searchBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: "searchMap:")
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(searchBtn, animated: false)
}
```

The list button works correctly. However, clicking the search button again does not take me back to the searchMap() method like it should. It deletes the left navigation bar button does it doesn't show the search bar. Is this because I've already created the searchDisplayController?

I'm also having the same issue after I search the map. After I search the map, the search bar disappears like it should but I have the same issue when I click the search button again. Here is that method.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked( searchBar: UISearchBar!)
{
    var listBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "List", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goToList:")
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(listBtn, animated: false)

    var searchBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: "searchMap:")
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(searchBtn, animated: false)

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    var found = false
    for bar in bars {
        var barName = bar.name.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\'", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
        var searchString = searchBar.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\'", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

        var test = bar as BarAnnotation
        if barName.rangeOfString(searchString) != nil || barName.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchString.lowercaseString) != nil {
            found = true
            var span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005, 0.005)
            var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: test.location, span: span)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            mapView.selectAnnotation(bar.annotation, animated: true)
        }
    }

    if found {
        // Need to go back to original state

        searchBar.hidden = true
        searchBar.text = ""
    }
    else{
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Not Found"
        alert.message = "Not found. Please try your search again."
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alert.show()

        searchBar.text = ""
    }
}
```

Any ideas??

**BONUS:** Is there a way to dynamically resize my search bar depending on the phone? When I initialized it I said

```
var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 20)) as UISearchBar
```

But that won't be the correct values for an iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe I didn't see this, but I just needed

```
searchBar.hidden = false
```

in the SearchMap() method. I'm still having trouble trying to figure out the dynamic resizing if anyone has any advice on that.

Comment: Hi @leerob i have implemented the same,but when i click on cancel button it does not call the method searchBarCancelButtonClicked.In result search bar is not hiding on click cancel button.

Comment: @Daljeet I believe you need to set the search bars delegate to whatever class you're working in so it can recognize when the cancel button is clicked.

Comment: i have already added delegates UISearchControllerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your search bar to searchBar.sizeToFit() and it will dynamically resize your search bar for different devices.

Comment: I also found that setting the searchBar to navigationBar.title and not passing in size parameters will make it auto-resize.